# how to pass optional parameter in views.py [ Django ]

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

urls.py:

```
def shopgrid(request, proname=None):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    categories = Categories.objects.all()
    recent_products = Product.objects.order_by('-date')[0:3]
    if proname != None:
        products = Product.objects.filter(categorie__title=proname)
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        recent = request.GET.get('val')
        amount = request.GET.get('amount')
        print('This is amount--->',amount)

        if recent == 'name':
            products = Product.objects.order_by('name')
        if recent == 'price':
            products = Product.objects.order_by('-price')

    if  'val' in request.GET:
        check_values = request.GET.getlist('val')
        first_element=check_values[0]
        last_element=check_values[-1]
        fe = first_element[0:4]
        le = last_element[-4:]
        min_price = int(fe)
        max_price = int(le)

        products = Product.objects.filter(price__range=(min_price, max_price))
        print(products)
            
    context={'p':products, 'rp':recent_products, 'cat':categories}
    return render(request, 'cart/shop-grid.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('shopgrid/', views.shopgrid, name="shopgrids"),
    path('shopgrid/<str:proname>/', views.shopgrid, name="shopgrid"),
    path('cat_sort/<str:proname>/', views.cat_sort, name="cat_sort"),
]
```

ERROR:

```
**Reverse for 'shopgrid' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shopgrid/(?P<proname>[^/]+)/$']**

<form id="priceform" action="**{% url 'shopgrid' %}**" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Add Your Price">                      
</form>
```

def shopgrid(request, **proname=None**):
proname is an optional parameter.Question is how to write optional parameter in Jinja template.
i already write a proname=None but I am facing error only HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the view *without* a parameter is `shopgrids`, so the url should be:

```
<form id="priceform" action="{% url 'shopgrids' %}" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Add Your Price">
</form>
```